# Symfony: Form EntityType loading from another database

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

Symfony 4.x project using a doctrine with multiple database connections.
I have **Customers** in one database and **Locations** in another database.
I have a **CustomerForm** that I use to enter and edit information about the customer, including Location.   I need to build a list of locations in the form in a select list, so I have a definition such as:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Lobbytrack\Location;
use App\Repository\Lobbytrack\LocationRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CustomerForm extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
         ...

          $builder
            ->add('location', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'Location',
                'class' => Location::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('l')
                        ->where('l.isActive = 1')
                        ->orderBy('l.order',' ASC');
                },
            ])

          ...
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'App\Entity\Customer'
    ));
}
```

When I try to load the form, it throws an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'smc.location' doesn't exist
```

So it appears that it's using my default database connection, rather than the connection that contains locations, even though I've included the correct Location class and Repository.

How can I get this query to use the correct connection?
Or is there another way to build this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Specify the 'em' option to the formBuilder :

```
          $builder
        ->add('location', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => 'Location',
            'class' => Location::class,
            'em'  => 'custom_1'
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('l')
                    ->where('l.isActive = 1')
                    ->orderBy('l.order',' ASC');
            },
        ])
```

### config/packages/doctrine.yaml:

```
    dbal:
 #        url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver: pdo_pgsql
                driver_class: App\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\CustomPostgreSQLDriver
                host: '%env(DATABASE_HOST)%' 
                port: '%env(DATABASE_PORT)%' 
                dbname: '%env(DATABASE_NAME)%' 
                user: '%env(DATABASE_USER)%' 
                password: '%env(DATABASE_PASSWORD)%' 
                charset: UTF8
            custom_1:
                driver: pdo_pgsql
                ...
```

Another option is to provide 'em' instance and not just the string name.